# Thoroughly Cleaning Out App Data for Clean Build?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, build

I have never had a problem like this but its clear a thorough clean out of all app data related to my project needs to be done as I am getting a crash related to UICollectionView which I have no removed any reference to in its entirety. I have tested the build on the simulator after resting its contents and it runs without the crash.

For building to my iPhone, I have deleted the app, restarted my iPhone, cleaned the project in Xcode, quit Xcode, restarted my computer and re-built and run. However my iPhone seems to be remembering something from that old build, resulting in this error to still be prevelent.

So how can I truly once and for all (without restoring my bleeding iPhone) clean out any old data related to my Xcode build?

Thanks.

Comment: After deleting the app try reseting your phone and see if that helps. I know it seems crazy but I have had this issue and after deleting the app I reset my device and the lingering data was deleted.

Comment: You should not have to reset the phone.  I do not suggest it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the app on your phone should be sufficient.  Your phone will not "remember" the app, as you suggest it might be.  The only thing an app can physically leave behind after being deleted is anything that it put into the Keychain, such as a username/password that was saved there.  Other than that, nothing can be left behind after an app deletion (at least not for practical purposes, I'm not trying to claim that iOS zeroes out the bits).

That said, obviously do a clean in Xcode and then delete your derived data.  For full instructions on doing a complete clean, see the answer to the following question: [How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the Derived Data in Organizer? Press Command-Shift-2 and go to the Projects tab. Under your projects you should see a long path to Derived Data. Delete that, restart your computer, and let Xcode reindex your project. [Link to a screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/453pynyu6qh98bh/Screen%20Shot%202013-08-13%20at%2020.54.23.png)